# Timer Using Javascript in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Below are the controller and view of my application from controller m passing the difference of start time and end time in duration and I want to access this duration to view page so i can assign duration value to `javascript timer and start the clock I have done using viewbag but i m getting null value i m working on online examination and i want to start a timer like countdown time when user click on start
in it can anybody help  I m creating a timer control by taking the difference between two times in mvc

```
public ActionResult ApplyForTest(int Test_Id)
        {
            EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal stuBal = new EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal();
            ViewBag.TestId = Test_Id;
            DataTable testSchedule = stuBal.getTestDateTime(Test_Id);
            ViewBag.Sysdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            ViewBag.SysTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            for (int i = 0; i < testSchedule.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Test Date_Time = new Test();
                ViewBag.Test_Date = testSchedule.Rows[i]["Test_Date"].ToString();
                ViewBag.Start_Time = testSchedule.Rows[i]["Start_Time"].ToString();
                ViewBag.End_Time = testSchedule.Rows[i]["End_Time"].ToString();

                DateTime strtTime = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Start_Time);
                DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.End_Time);

                TimeSpan duration = (endTime - strtTime);
                ViewBag.a = duration;

            }
            return View();
        }




          @model List<EAssessmentNew.Models.Question>



            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "TestStarted";
                Layout = "~/Views/StudentMaster.cshtml";
                TimeSpan t = ViewBag.a;

            }


                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
                    var d = '@ViewBag.duration';
                    alert(d);
                    var testDate = '@ViewBag.Test_Date';
                    var startTime = '@ViewBag.Start_Time';
                    var EndTime = '@ViewBag.End_Time';

                    d.setHours(00, d, 59, 00);
                    function myTimer() {

                        if (d.getSeconds() <= 1)
                            d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 1, 59, 00);

                        var h = d.getHours();
                        var m = d.getMinutes();
                        var s = d.getSeconds() - 1;


                        if (m == 0 && s == 1)
                            window.location.href = "showresults.aspx";
                        document.getElementById("lblCtime").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":"s;

                        d.setMinutes(m, s);
                        //setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
                    }
                </script>
```

Above mention are the controller and view of my application from controller m passing the difference of start time and end time in duration and i want to access this duration to view page so i can assign duration value to `javascript timer and start the clock i hv done using viewbag but i m getting null value i m working on online examination and i want to start a timer like countdown time when user click on start
in it can anybody help  I m creating a timer control by taking the difference between two times in mvc

I have used all the required javascript but m getting null value on viewpage viewbag

Comment: punctuation. please. Maybe mention that is is ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously take a look at SignalR for this instead of doing this in javascript. You can have your timer run on the server tied to a particular web connection to the SignalR hub and then have the SignalR Hub broadcast to your javascript method the running clock.